# Filter names with more criteria

Tags: r, filter

I needed to do the following steps to a large data set, I tried to use `filter` but can't correctly achieve what I expected.

In the data example I put below, there are four columns: `subject`,`block number`,`US`,`stimulus`.

```
    subject block number US stimulus
1 subject1            3  0      S10
2 subject1            3  1       S1
3 subject1            4  0      S10
4 subject1            4  0       S7
5 subject1            4  1       S1
6 subject1            4  0       S8
```

1. For every subject (I only put subject 1's data as example), if `US==1` in `block number==3`, then `stimulus` becomes `'CS+'`; if `US == 0` in `block number == 3`, then stimulus becomes `'CS-'`.
2. I needed to apply this to stimulus in all the block numbers. For example, if for subject 1, `S10 == CS+` in `block number==3`, then `S10` also == `CS+` in other block numbers. And other stimulus name remained the same.

I know how to use filter to change the names of stimulus in `block number==3`, but I don't know how to generalize this to other block numbers.

```
structure(list(subject = c("subject1", "subject1", "subject1", 
"subject1", "subject1", "subject1"), `block number` = c(3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), US = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), stimulus = c("S10", 
"S1", "S10", "S7", "S1", "S8")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000261ebfe1ef0>)
```

---

updated question:

In the table below, `US==1` happens two times for `S10` but only one time for `S1`, can I then set a criteria that if, for each subject, the amount of `US == 1` for a stimulus (`S10` in this example) > the amount of `US == 1` for another stimulus (`S1` in this example), then the former be named as '`CS+`' and the later be named as '`CS-`'? And then apply this to other block numbers as my original question.

```
subject block number US stimulus
1 subject1            3  1      S10
2 subject1            3  1      S10
3 subject1            3  1       S1
4 subject1            3  0       S1
5 subject1            4  0      S10
6 subject1            4  0       S7
7 subject1            4  1       S1
8 subject1            4  0       S8
```

```
structure(list(subject = c("subject1", "subject1", "subject1", 
                           "subject1", "subject1", "subject1", "subject1", "subject1"), `block number` = c(3L, 3L,3L,3L, 
                                                                                   4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), US = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L,1L,0L), stimulus = c("S10", 'S10',
                                                                                                                                                 "S1", 'S1',"S10", "S7", "S1", "S8")), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("data.frame"))
```

Comment: @AnilGoyal Yes, in the real data I have many block numbers. In all other block numbers I have many different stimulus, and in bock number 3 there will be only 2 stimulus, and I need to change the names of these two stimulus to all the block numbers based on the condition in block number 3.

Comment: @AnilGoyal Sorry about that, I will minimize data sample further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Revised Scenario**

```
data %>% group_by(subject, stimulus) %>%
  mutate(dummy = sum(`block number` == 3 & US == 1)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% group_by(subject) %>%
  mutate(new_stimulus = case_when(`block number` == 3 & dummy == max(dummy) ~ 'US+',
                                  `block number` == 3 ~ 'US-',
                                  TRUE ~ stimulus)) %>%
  group_by(subject, stimulus) %>%
  mutate(new_stimulus = ifelse(min(new_stimulus == stimulus) < 1, new_stimulus, stimulus)) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 8 x 6
  subject  `block number`    US stimulus dummy new_stimulus
  <chr>             <int> <int> <chr>    <int> <chr>       
1 subject1              3     1 S10          2 US+         
2 subject1              3     1 S10          2 US+         
3 subject1              3     1 S1           1 US-         
4 subject1              3     0 S1           1 US-         
5 subject1              4     0 S10          2 US+         
6 subject1              4     0 S7           0 S7          
7 subject1              4     1 S1           1 US-         
8 subject1              4     0 S8           0 S8
```

You may remove `dummy` variable if you want.

**Earlier scenario**

```
data %>% mutate(new_stimulus = case_when(`block number` == 3 & US == 1 ~ 'CS+',
                                `block number` == 3 & US == 0 ~ 'CS-',
                                TRUE ~ stimulus)) %>%
  group_by(subject, stimulus) %>%
  mutate(new_stimulus = ifelse(min(new_stimulus == stimulus) < 1, new_stimulus, stimulus)) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 6 x 5
  subject  `block number`    US stimulus new_stimulus
  <chr>             <int> <int> <chr>    <chr>       
1 subject1              3     0 S10      CS-         
2 subject1              3     1 S1       CS+         
3 subject1              4     0 S10      CS-         
4 subject1              4     0 S7       S7          
5 subject1              4     1 S1       CS+         
6 subject1              4     0 S8       S8
```

Comment: Sorry, may I also ask what can I do if I need a criteria: 'CS+' if 'the number of US==1 > the number of US==0'? e.g., if S10 ==1 two times and S1 ==1 one time then S10 == 'CS+'

Comment: Can you please elaborate with an example?

Comment: See edit, please.  It should be working!!